# TPL Dataflow Transform block post to two action block in parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have a TPL Dataflow, that worked fine using only a transform block, then an action block.
I've added a new action block to be executed simultaneously with the existing action block, but my new action block is never getting hit. There are no errors or exceptions being thrown.
Is there a step that I need to add to my code?

```
var ListDocId = new ConcurrentBag<string>(ConvertDataSetToList(IdDocDataSet));

if (ListDocId.Any())
{
    var num_thread = GetThreadNumber();

    //Initialize the pipeline of actions
    var downloadBlock = new TransformBlock<string, RequestObject>(docId =>
        new RequestObject
        {
            DownloadedFile = ListDownloadocId),
            IdDoc = docId
        },
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }
    );

    var uploadInS3Block = new ActionBlock<S3RequestUpload>(requestS3Upload =>
        UploadFileAsync(RequestObject.DownloadedFile, RequestObject.IdDoc),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }
    );

    var InsertdocIdIntoDbBlock = new ActionBlock<RequestObject>(s3Request =>
        InsertIntotDataBase(s3Request.IdDoc, InsertDate),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }
    );

    var options = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true };

    downloadBlock.LinkTo(uploadInS3Block, options);
    downloadBlock.LinkTo(InsertdocIdIntoDbBlock, options);

    foreach (var idDoc in ListDocId)
        downloadInAsterionBlock.Post(idDoc);

    downloadBlock.Complete();
    //uploadInS3Block.Completion.Wait();
    //InsertdocIdIntoDbBlock.Completion.Wait();
    Task.WhenAll(uploadInS3Block.Completion,
        InsertdocIdIntoDbBlock.Completion).Wait();
```

Comment: downloadBlock and uploadInS3Block works correctly, but the InsertdocIdIntoDbBlock is never getting hit !

Comment: Your code isn't the real deal is it? Is `downloadInAsterionBlock` the same as `downloadBlock `?. Also you are linking a transformblock with type `RequestObject` to an actionblock with type `S3RequestUpload`

Comment: Thanks Peter, i edited the code with the same (downloadBlock)

Comment: I use RequestObject because i have to pass more than one parameter and i can't use tuple (C# 5)

Comment: There is a syntax error in this line: `DownloadedFile = ListDownloadocId),`

Answer (score 5):

You cannot link a `TransformBlock` to more than one other block. So only the first call to `downloadInAsterionBlock.LinkTo()` is considered.

You need to put in a `BroadcastBlock` between the `downloadBlock` and the two `ActionBlock` blocks.

```
downloadBlock -> broadcastBlock -> uploadInS3Block
                                -> InsertdocIdIntoDbBlock
```

In code it will look like this:

```cs
var bc = new BroadcastBlock<RequestObject>(ro => ro);

downloadBlock.LinkTo(bc);
bc.LinkTo(uploadInS3Block);
bc.LinkTo(InsertdocIdIntoDbBlock);
```

Comment: Thank you Peter, now the processing reaches the last method (InsertIntotDataBase) well, however I have an AccessViolationException when executing the last method that inserts the data into the database, i add the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute but i steel can't handle it.

Comment: @NHARIMed I think it is best to create new question for that as it has no relationship with using Dataflow blocks.

Comment: Ok, thank you Peter!